# What existing engines can do open-world games?

Tags: open-world

I'm looking for a 3D engine that would allow me to do open-world games.
Basically:
- the game is looks like one big "map" of several km wide where you can walk from one point to another
- there would be a possibility to fly so I can't compute in advance how much of the terrain is visible (you can fly up and see a lot of things around you)
- should handle a day/night cycle (so I can't really pre-compute a general lightning since it would change)

I don't really need something that would be very performant because I don't plan on havings lots and lots of models etc (I'm not doing a AAA game), I'm mainly looking for a solution that is scalable, ie not something where I just load all the game assets in memory for the whole world and then not display most of it.

Do you know any engines (possibly free and open source) who can currently handle this? I tried looking at how to do this with Ogre but I don't think it's really possible

Comment: Ogre is a rendering engine, you could certainly implement this using Ogre as the renderer though. This feels too much like a "which technology" question to me, though.

Comment: The engine doesn't dictate what types of games you can make

Comment: @Bugster, That is not entirely true. Some engines are specifically designed (read: Optimized )for certain game play/style/mechanics. In the end you could build your own components/features(depending on how modular the "game" engine is). But in that case any "generic" engine that provides rendering/audio/input will do. Mostly they are not exactly game engines. Just like Ogre/Irrlicht/SFML. You just build your game on top of it.

Comment: @Bugster, nvm. I read it as "game-engine". my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Every engine can do it, you just need to know how to do it. Make enough big map, with all features what you wanna to have. After  that, code/script everything. Then you can add features to the game, new models,maps and etc.